# C++ headers missing from new c++ versions

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I checked the c++ reference website: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/
I cannot see many of the header files i knew and used, like the "iostream.h", or "conio.h".
Why is that?
Are they replaced with new?
If that's true. what more 'old' header files are replaced?
Can i see somewhere this "progress", so to stay up to speed?
And when i write code that include the iostream.h for example it is running flawlessly. Is this for backwards compatibility? Shouldn't i have to see a compiler warning?

EDIT: To make some clarifications, the `.h` standard has been deprecated in C++.
Also, do not use

```
<iostream.h>
```

Since the 98 standard it has also been deprecated, the header iostream.h is a non-standard header and does not exist on all platforms. Code that uses it should be considered non-standard legacy code and is not portable.

You shoud use `<iostream>` instead.

Finally, `conio.h` is a C header file used mostly by MS-DOS compilers to provide console input/output. It is not part of the C standard library or ISO C, nor is it defined by POSIX.

This means, avoid using this too, if you are on a system which supports it.

Comment: Neither of those files have ever been standard C++ or C headers.

Comment: _... iostream.h ..._ `.h` file extension for [tag:c++] standard headers, is deprecated since aeons ago! Welcome to 2014 ...

Comment: Oh too bad, I thought they might have actually removed some things from c++.